# Nothing happens when clicking on new reputation points

Tags: bug, ios-app

Recently, when clicking on the field for new incoming reputation points (in the top right corner), nothing happens.

I have the feeling that when clicking in between the notification icon and the points icon, the points menu is opening while it does not when clicking right in the middle of the points icon. I only experience clicking problems in the SE app.

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)